# In Ruby TracePoint, can you force stop the execution of the call being traced?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

The goal of the method I am writing is to run every method called within a block argument in parallel.

I am exploring using TracePoint, which I am using to determine when each method inside the block is called, where I fork a process and call the method, however I can't find a way to then stop the default method execution.

I tried re-defining the method being called using define_singleton_method within the TracePoint block, which correctly alters the method for the NEXT execution of it, but the current execution still happens unaltered.  Is there a way within TracePoint to stop execution of the method currently being traced?  Alternatively, is there a way to accomplish my goal without using TracePoint?

Some simplified code to illustrate:

```
def my_method(&block)
  trace = TracePoint.new(:call) do |tp|
    tp.disable
    method = tp.self.method(tp.method_id)

    @args = []
    method.parameters.each { |param|
      @args.push(tp.binding.eval("#{param.last}"))
    }

    fork do
      # This executes the method in it's own process with the same
      # arguments given in the traced call
      result = method.call(*@args)
    end

    tp.enable
  end

  trace.enable
  block.call
  trace.disable
end
```

After my code gets executed inside the TracePoint block and before block.call returns, the method within the block gets executed again in the main process. How can I prevent that from happening?

Comment: I ended up solving the problem in a different way using a BlankSlate Proxy class. You can see the solution here: https://github.com/samwoods1/in-parallel. I'll leave this question open though since I am still curious about the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could raise an exception inside of your TracePoint callback, and then catch and ignore it outside.